# Use Functions in different classes in Java without collecting it in a class as methods

Tags: java, class, function, methods

I have some functions collected as methods in a class called `func`. I use those methods quite often in different classes. Is there a way in java to call those functions without creating a new object or calling it like this: `func.myFunction();`?

I want: `myFunction();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

- you can't call non-static methods without having an instance of that class *and*
- you can't directly call static methods without mentioning the class name.

The first one is easy to solve: if your method doesn't actually use any non-static members (fields or methods) of the class, then simply adding the `static` keyword enables you to call it without an instance of the class:

```
// in YourClass:
public static void yourMethod() {
  //stuff
}

// somewhere else:
YourClass.yourMethod();
```

And about the second item: I kind-of lied there, you *can* do that, but you need a static import:

```
// at the beginning of your .java file
import static yourpackage.YourClass.yourMethod;

// later on in that file:
yourMethod();
```

Also: there are no functions in Java, only methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mark the methods as `static`, and use [static imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Example:

**pkg/UtilFunctions.java**

```
package pkg;

public class UtilFunctions {

    public static int sum(int i1, int i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import static pkg.UtilFunctions.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = sum(5, 7);     // Calls UtilFunctions.sum(...)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make them static like `public static int myFunction();` and then make static import: `import static myclass`:

```
Foo.java:
class Foo {
    public static int method() {return 42;}
    ...
}
Bar.java
import static Foo.*;
...
System.out.println(method());
```

Comment: `import static myclass` won't do, you'll have to import the particular static members of `myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static import.

For example this:

```
import java.lang.Math;
...
System.out.println(Math.abs(-1.4));
```

and this:

```
import static java.lang.Math;
...
System.out.println(abs(-1.4));
```

produce the same result.